# Вертикальный разделитель между ссылками меню

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, menu

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать такие разделители между ссылками меню?

Comment: Посмотрите под отладчиком...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже что это знак разорванной вертикальной черты "¦". В HTML его можно обозначить как `&brvbar;` или `&#166;`